# closing connection for resultset in jdbc in DAO layer

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset

I am reading this [excellent post](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) from [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), highly reputed and active StackOverflow member.

In the post, I find that that the `connection` nor the `resultSet` is closed after database access is finished. I am pretty sure I am missing something or have overlooked. I just want to know how the connection is closed.

Infact towards the very end of the post, he mentions about the how the code handles returning of connection to pool. but I don't see how it is happenening.

```
public void close() throws SQLException {
        if (this.connection is still eligible for reuse) {
            do not close this.connection, but just return it to pool for reuse;
        } else {
            actually invoke this.connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Here is the relevant class (with due respect to BalusC)

```
package com.example.dao;

import static com.example.dao.DAOUtil.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.model.User;

/**
 * This class represents a concrete JDBC implementation of the {@link UserDAO} interface.
 *
 * @author BalusC
 * @link http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html
 */
public class UserDAOJDBC implements UserDAO {

    // Constants ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final String SQL_FIND_BY_ID =
        "SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname, birthdate FROM User WHERE id = ?";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_BY_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD =
        "SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname, birthdate FROM User WHERE email = ? AND password = MD5(?)";
    private static final String SQL_LIST_ORDER_BY_ID =
        "SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname, birthdate FROM User ORDER BY id";
    private static final String SQL_INSERT =
        "INSERT INTO User (email, password, firstname, lastname, birthdate) VALUES (?, MD5(?), ?, ?, ?)";
    private static final String SQL_UPDATE =
        "UPDATE User SET email = ?, firstname = ?, lastname = ?, birthdate = ? WHERE id = ?";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE =
        "DELETE FROM User WHERE id = ?";
    private static final String SQL_EXIST_EMAIL =
        "SELECT id FROM User WHERE email = ?";
    private static final String SQL_CHANGE_PASSWORD =
        "UPDATE User SET password = MD5(?) WHERE id = ?";

    // Vars ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private DAOFactory daoFactory;

    // Constructors -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Construct an User DAO for the given DAOFactory. Package private so that it can be constructed
     * inside the DAO package only.
     * @param daoFactory The DAOFactory to construct this User DAO for.
     */
    UserDAOJDBC(DAOFactory daoFactory) {
        this.daoFactory = daoFactory;
    }

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public User find(Long id) throws DAOException {
        return find(SQL_FIND_BY_ID, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User find(String email, String password) throws DAOException {
        return find(SQL_FIND_BY_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD, email, password);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the user from the database matching the given SQL query with the given values.
     * @param sql The SQL query to be executed in the database.
     * @param values The PreparedStatement values to be set.
     * @return The user from the database matching the given SQL query with the given values.
     * @throws DAOException If something fails at database level.
     */
    private User find(String sql, Object... values) throws DAOException {
        User user = null;

        try (
            Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, sql, false, values);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        ) {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                user = map(resultSet);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }

        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> list() throws DAOException {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        try (
            Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_ORDER_BY_ID);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        ) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                users.add(map(resultSet));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }

        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public void create(User user) throws IllegalArgumentException, DAOException {
        if (user.getId() != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User is already created, the user ID is not null.");
        }

        Object[] values = {
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            user.getFirstname(),
            user.getLastname(),
            toSqlDate(user.getBirthdate())
        };

        try (
            Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_INSERT, true, values);
        ) {
            int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (affectedRows == 0) {
                throw new DAOException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
            }

            try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                    user.setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
                } else {
                    throw new DAOException("Creating user failed, no generated key obtained.");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) throws DAOException {
        if (user.getId() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User is not created yet, the user ID is null.");
        }

        Object[] values = {
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getFirstname(),
            user.getLastname(),
            toSqlDate(user.getBirthdate()),
            user.getId()
        };

        try (
            Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_UPDATE, false, values);
        ) {
            int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (affectedRows == 0) {
                throw new DAOException("Updating user failed, no rows affected.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) throws DAOException {
        Object[] values = { 
            user.getId()
        };

        try (
            Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_DELETE, false, values);
        ) {
            int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (affectedRows == 0) {
                throw new DAOException("Deleting user failed, no rows affected.");
            } else {
                user.setId(null);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean existEmail(String email) throws DAOException {
        Object[] values = { 
            email
        };

        boolean exist = false;

        try (
            Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_EXIST_EMAIL, false, values);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        ) {
            exist = resultSet.next();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }

        return exist;
    }

    @Override
    public void changePassword(User user) throws DAOException {
        if (user.getId() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User is not created yet, the user ID is null.");
        }

        Object[] values = {
            user.getPassword(),
            user.getId()
        };

        try (
            Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_CHANGE_PASSWORD, false, values);
        ) {
            int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (affectedRows == 0) {
                throw new DAOException("Changing password failed, no rows affected.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
    }

    // Helpers ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Map the current row of the given ResultSet to an User.
     * @param resultSet The ResultSet of which the current row is to be mapped to an User.
     * @return The mapped User from the current row of the given ResultSet.
     * @throws SQLException If something fails at database level.
     */
    private static User map(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
        user.setFirstname(resultSet.getString("firstname"));
        user.setLastname(resultSet.getString("lastname"));
        user.setBirthdate(resultSet.getDate("birthdate"));
        return user;
    }

}
```

I found out that one of the comments in the post had similar question but I guess, BalusC did not get time to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BalusC is using the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, which automatically closes the connection (and the statement, and the resultset) that is being opened inside the parentheses of the try block.

Comment: huh!. I missed that. how is the connection returned to pool? is closing automatically returns connection to pool?

Comment: Yes. A pooled connection overrides the close() method in order to just return to the pool.